# PHP - Convert a GMT Time in 12 Hour Format to new Timezone with a delay time

Tags: php, time

I receive 12 hour time format from GPS tracker .
example , GPS time : `8:25:40` in GMT0 (in 12hour format)
GPS sent this time with a delay may be in range of 1~20 minute

receive time from GPS with `00:2:15` delay on `2012-07-27 23:27:55` with `Europe/Moscow` timezone

***P.S**: on above data , result of my GPS time must be `2012-07-27 23:25:40`*

***Question:***
How can I specify GPS time in my Timezone (`Europe/Moscow`) ?

Comment: You want to get the delay offset without knowing the original timezone?

Comment: maybe you should go with the jQuery

Comment: Wait. Does the 12-hour time format you receive from the GPS contain an AM/PM? Because if not, you're utterly screwed in a completely different way.

Comment: @Truth I want to specify my GPS tracker time in my timezone from 12hour time in GMT0 sent from GPS tracker with a delay

Comment: @Palladium problem is that , GPS don't specify PM/AM . just sent time in 12 hour format in GMT0

Comment: @McKay: If you have no AM/PM, you can never accurately know if it's morning or evening.

Comment: Do you receive the delay value as well?

Comment: @Truth can specify when received that time from GPS , delay  time may be in 1~20 minute range .

Comment: `8:25:40 PM GMT` is `2012-07-28 00:25:40` in Moscow time, are you sure it should be `23:25:40` (is the GPS in `GMT` or `Europe/London`)?

Comment: @salathe GPS time is based on GMT0 , GPS time :`8:25:40` + `3:00` on new timezone with `12:00` , result will be `23:25:40`

Comment: Europe/Moscow is currently GMT + 4 hours, not 3.

Comment: @salathe which my confirm my theory of interview task because I haven't seen GPS that sucks like that...

Comment: @webarto My GPS tracker have a Horrible data query... :-"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$gps_time      = "9:43:52";
$time_received = "01:45:04 2012-07-28";

$utc    = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
$moscow = new DateTimeZone("Europe/Moscow");

//Instantiate both AM and PM versions of your time
$gps_time_am = new DateTime("$gps_time AM", $utc);
$gps_time_pm = new DateTime("$gps_time PM", $utc);

//Received time
$time_received = new DateTime($time_received, $moscow);

//Change timezone to Moscow
$gps_time_am->setTimezone($moscow);
$gps_time_pm->setTimezone($moscow);

//Check the difference in hours. If it's less than 1 hour difference, it's the correct one.
if ($time_received->diff($gps_time_pm)->h < 1) {
    echo $gps_time_pm->format("H:i:s Y-m-d");
}
else {
    echo $gps_time_am->format("H:i:s Y-m-d");
}
```

Make sure to specify the exact date of the received time to prevent oddities.

P.S. Moscow is in Europe.

Comment: he doesn't know the gps am/pm

Comment: yeah, so your answer could be off by 12 hours. Not acceptable.

Comment: Yeah, this is beginning to look like the answer I've got.

Comment: @McKay: There, tested with both 23:... and 11:... it works as expected.

Comment: what if the diff returns a negative -11.75? Or does diff always do absolute values?

Comment: Diff always returns absolute values. If the difference is negative, the `inverted` field in the `DateInterval` class is 1 instead of 0.

Comment: @McKay You can return an absolute difference using the second argument of `diff()`.

Comment: Why have the bother of deciding whether it's AM or PM? The OP states that the GPS time will be at some point up to 20 minutes delayed, no more.

Comment: @salathe, Truth is now correct here, this level of comparison is required. What if that 20 minutes overlaps a day boundary.

Comment: now what if received time with `5min delay` on `00:02:30` night ? and GPS time is must be `8:57:30` , above code is ok ?

Comment: He could just check to see whether the AM time makes sense, if not then roll over to PM.

Comment: @Truth I must specify `$gps_time_pm`/`$gps_time_am` on `//It's PM! & //It's AM!` ?

Comment: @IR_Designer: See updated code. Output is the correct time in your own timezone. Fiddle with the top 2 variables to see the code in action.

Comment: @IR_Designer: [Let's continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14544/discussion-between-truth-and-ir-designer)

Comment: @Truth have problem , I test it : time was sent:`GPS Time = 9:43:52`, new time specify with above code : `Correct Time= 12:43:52 2012-07-27` , and my timezone time :`Now time = 01:45:04 2012-07-28` ... (edit:) My Codes on Pastebin: [http://pastebin.com/EjgVx2a5]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function correct_time($time)
{
    $yesterday = false;
    $tomorrow = false;

    #offset = abs(date('h') - (int) $time);
    $offset = '3';

    $time_of_day = ($hour < 12)? 'AM': 'PM';

    if($hour < 0)
    {
        $yesterday = true;
        $time_of_day = 'PM';
    }
    if($hour > 12)
    {
        $tomorrow = true;
        $time_of_day = 'AM';       
    }

    $screwed_gps_time = $time . ' ' . $time_of_day;

    $gps_time = new DateTime($screwed_gps_time, new DateTimeZone("Europe/London"));
    if($yesterday)
    {
        $gps_time->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }
    if($tomorrow)
    {
        $gps_time->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }
    $gps_time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));

    return $gps_time->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");    
}

echo correct_time('8:25:40'); # 2012-07-27 23:25:40
echo correct_time('1:25:40'); # 2012-07-28 04:25:40
echo correct_time('11:25:40'); # 2012-07-28 02:25:40
```

too many cases to cover here

Comment: Offset is not constant; this code has the potential to mess up PM entries as AM.

Comment: Yeah, what if you don't know the offset?

Comment: @McKay: But you do know the offset. He said so himself, from GMT+0 (eg. London) to Moscow. I don't even care which GMT zone is Moscow, PHP will handle it by itself.

Comment: @Palladium honestly, this sounds to me more like an interview task, I worked with GPSes, and I refuse to believe that ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember all of my PHP libraries, so

Pseudocode algorithm:

```
AdjustTimeToGPS(gpsTime : 12HourTime, currentTime : DayAndTime, currentTimeZone : TimeZone) : DayAndTime
begin
    gmtCurrentTime : DayAndTime := ConvertToGmt(currentTime, currentTimeZone);
    gmtCurrent12HourTime : 12HourTime := 12HourFromDayAndTime(gmtCurrentTime);
    gpsHour : Hour := GetHourFrom12HourTime(gpsTime); // hour is 0 to 11;
    gmtCurrentHour : Hour := GetHourFrom12HourTime(gmtCurrent12Hour);
    day : Day := GetDayFromDayAndTime(gmtCurrentTime);
    isPm : Boolean = IsPM(gmtCurrentTime);

    if (gmtCurrentHour == 0 AND gpsHour == 11)
    begin    
        // we need to subtract 12 hours
        isPm := Not(isPm);

        if (isPM)
        begin
            // we looped. need to subtract a day
            day := day - 1;
        end
    end

    if (gmtCurrentHour == 11 AND gpsHour == 0)
    begin    
        // we need to add 12 hours
        isPm := Not(isPm);

        if (Not(isPM))
        begin
            // we looped. need to add a day
            day := day + 1;
        end
    end

    return DayAndTimeFrom12Hour(gpsTime, isPM, day);
end
```

Comment: You don't need to do this sort of time parsing in PHP, PHP's DateTime object does all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: @truth I never said this was PHP. I said this was pseudocode designed to help the reader understand the algorithm. Yeah, call PHP functions to get the hours. Don't do parsing.